# Mongo DB update query throwing error

Tags: mongodb

I have been trying to update the one filed using update query but it has throwing the error , please help.

```
Query:
    db.dumpbasiccompany.update(
    db.dumpbasiccompany.aggregate([{ $lookup: { from: "basiccompany", localField: "CompanyName",  foreignField: "CompanyName", as: "inventory_docs"}},{ $project : {"_id":1 } } ]),
    { $set:{ flag: 1 } }) 

    Error:
    WriteResult({
            "nMatched" : 0,
            "nUpserted" : 0,
            "nModified" : 0,
            "writeError" : {
                    "code" : 2,
                    "errmsg" : "cannot compare to undefined"
            }
    })
```

I am new people of mongo db so I am not sure about this , Kindly validated my query.

Comment: This is wrong way to update. And what you need to expected result..
Note : give sample document to you have. And some explanation.

Comment: Hi Sathish , My requirement is compare to the two collections , If same records coming I need to update flag value.

Comment: like you need to find collection1 and you check update collection2. Then your requirement matched means, weather update collection1 or collection2.

Comment: Thanks for your effort ,I have two collections dumpbasiccompany and basiccompany , I need to check CompanyName column , If CompanyName is same then update flag=1 to basiccompany collection. Hope you can provide the solution to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use code like this:

```
db.basiccompany.find().forEach(
    function(doc) {
        var check = false;
        data = db.dumpbasiccompany.find({
            CompanyName: doc.CompanyName
        }).forEach(function(mydoc) {
            if (mydoc != null) {
                check = true;
            }
        })
        if (check == true) {
            db.basiccompany.update({
                _id: doc._id
            }, {
                $set: {
                    flag: 1
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: @Antony. This is also based on your requirement. you need to check this.

Comment: It's working fine,Thanks ...You've been very helpful.